# How can I add value to nested JSON in Rest Assured framework?

Tags: json, groovy, rest-assured

I have the following block of JSON Response. I am using the `com.jayway.restassured.response.Response` class to read the response from the API.

```
{
    layouts:
    {
        regions:
        {
            [
                metadata: null, 
                endDate: null, 
                displayName: null, 
                roles: []
            ],  
            [
                metadata: null, 
                endDate: null, 
                displayName: null, 
                roles: []
            ]
        },
    }
}
```

I need to add the below structure into the regions array :

```
[
    structure: 100, 
    type: 101, 
    widgets: [], 
    width: 12
]
```

So that the resultant JSON looks like this :

```
{
    layouts:
    {
        regions:
        {
            [
                metadata: null, 
                endDate: null, 
                displayName: null, 
                roles: []
            ],
            [
                structure: 100, 
                type: 101, 
                widgets: [], 
                width: 12
            ],
            [
                metadata: null, 
                endDate: null, 
                displayName: null, 
                roles: []                   
            ]
        },
    }
}
```

What is the best way to do this? As I am using the `com.jayway.restassured.response.Response` response, `JSONSlurper` doesn't seem to work in parsing through the response. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide a correct JSON response? In correct JSON "regions" should be an Array, like that:

```
{
    layouts:
    {
        regions:
        [
            {
                metadata: null, 
                endDate: null, 
                displayName: null, 
                roles: []
            },  
            {
                metadata: null, 
                endDate: null, 
                displayName: null, 
                roles: []
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

And you can use LAX type for `JsonSlurper`:

```
def json = new JsonSlurper(type: JsonParserType.LAX).parseText(text)
JsonBuilder builder = new JsonBuilder()

List regionsList = json.layouts.regions
regionsList << [
        structure: 100,
        type: 101,
        widgets: [],
        width: 12
]

builder.layouts {
    regions(regionsList)
}

println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(builder.toString())
```

The code above produce next result:

```
{
    "layouts": {
        "regions": [
            {
                "metadata": null,
                "endDate": null,
                "displayName": null,
                "roles": [

                ]
            },
            {
                "metadata": null,
                "endDate": null,
                "displayName": null,
                "roles": [

                ]
            },
            {
                "structure": 100,
                "type": 101,
                "widgets": [

                ],
                "width": 12
            }
        ]
    }
}
```